# Question on an application of mean value theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a twice differential function $G(x_1, x_2)$. Let $I_1, I_2$ be some bounded intervals. 
I am interested in obtaining an upper bound for the quantity 
$$
\max_{x_i \in I_i} | (G(x_1, x_2) - G(a_1, x_2)) - (G(x_1, b_2) - G(a_1, b_2)) |,
$$
where $a_1 \in I_1$ $b_2 \in I_2$ are some fixed values. I was thinking maybe I can use mean value theorem to obtain an upper bound for this quantity in terms of the second derivative of $G$ or something, but I wasn't really sure. Could someone please tell me an upper bound one can get in terms of the derivatives of $G$? Any comments/solutions are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I write
$$G(x,y)-G(a,y)-G(x,b)+G(a,b)$$
instead?

For a fixed $x$, this is $h(y)-h(b)$ where $h(y)=G(x,y)-G(a,y)$. By MVT then
$$h(y)-h(b)=(y-b)h'(\eta)$$
where $\eta$ is between $b$ and $h$. Now
$$h'(\eta)=G_y(x,\eta)-G_y(a,\eta)$$
where $G_y$ is the partial derivative of $G(x,y)$ with respect to $y$.
By MVT again,
$$h'(\eta)=(x-a)G_{x,y}(\xi,\eta)$$
where $\xi$ is between $a$ and $x$, and $G_{x,y}$ is the mixed
second partial derivative.

We conclude that
$$|G(x,y)-G(a,y)-G(x,b)+G(a,b)|\le|x-a||y-b|M$$
where $M$ is any upper bound for $G_{x,y}$ on the region in question.